# How to call async function in Python Enum?

Tags: python, async-await, enums, python-asyncio, fastapi

I want to refactor my code from `sync` to `async`. I use Python and FastAPI.
I use the method which calls `async` function in Enumaration.

For example:

```py
from enum import Enum
from app.story import get_story

    StoriesEnum = Enum(
        "StoriesEnum", {story: story  for story in get_story.story_list},
    )
```

`get_story` is an `async` function that returns `Story` class and it has `story_list`.

How can I `await` the `get_story.story_list`?

I tried:

- `asyncio.run()`
- `get_event_loop()`
- `async` generator

with no successful result. They don't work because `await` is outside the `async` function.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I will take a look at this reproducible example link. Usually I don't ask questions, so I need time to make questions more readable and meet all requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/):

> You might have noticed that `await` can only be used inside of functions
> defined with `async def`.
>
> But at the same time, functions defined with `async def` have to be
> "awaited". So, functions with `async def` **can only be called inside of**
> **functions defined with** `async def` too.

Thus, what you could do is:

```py
import asyncio

async def go(): 
    return Enum("StoriesEnum", {s:s for s in (await get_story()).story_list.value})

StoriesEnum = asyncio.run(go())
print({e:e.value for e in StoriesEnum})
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details on `async` / `await` in FastAPI and Python in general.

Comment: Thank you, Chris.
I will take a look at this reproducible example link. Usually I don't ask questions, so I need time to make questions more readable and meet all requirements.